# Execute Update Query In WordPress From functions.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to execute an update query from my functions.php using init hook.

Here is my code

```
add_action('init', 'process_query');
function process_query(){
 $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET status='inactive' WHERE CURRENT_DATE NOT BETWEEN startdate AND enddate");
}
```

Now this query works fine when i directly run it on PHPmyadmin's SQL section. But if i put it to functions.php, the theme goes down and i get a blank webpage.
I have checked WordPress codex syntax for "update" query but it requires arrays. So it won't work for me in that way.

Comment: Where do you set the `$table_name` variable?

Comment: blank white page means find the syntax error

Comment: @MikeB
There might be a syntax error but I am not getting where could it be. I just have copy pasted the function I am working on. Can you please point out where the syntax error could be? Because as soon as I remove this bit of code from my functions.php, the site starts working again. So whatever is the problem, its in this bit of code...

Comment: @Symbolwdd You don't need to crowd-source syntax error problems http://codepad.org/MUpubgwj. Regardless, a lack of error message or feedback STILL means find the error message instead of randomly moving code around to see when it starts kicking again. You could be using a vertical tab somewhere that looks like a space and you'd never know unless you nail down the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Following Code

```
add_action('init', 'process_query');
    function process_query(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'enter_your_table_name_here';
     $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET status='inactive' WHERE CURRENT_DATE NOT BETWEEN startdate AND enddate");
    }
```